# Add new line after four commas in string

Tags: android, string, kotlin

Since I'm not able to find a solution to this problem I'm going to post here a question, hoping someone will help me.

I have a string like this `"One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, ..."` and I need to find a way to insert a new line (\n) after the fourth comma, in this case `"One, Two, Three, Four, \n Five, Six, ..."`.

 
And this is the code I'm trying to use

```
for (letters in ingredients.toString()) {
     var commasCount = 0

     if (letters.toString() == ",") {
         commasCount++

         if (commasCount == 4) {
            ingredients.toString().replace(",", "\n")
         }
     }
}
```

UPDATE:

This is my code now, no errors, no warnings but the output is now like this "[Ljava.lang.String@1c7172b" instead of the ingredients, what am I missing now ?

UPDATE PT.2:

```
database.collection("Pizze").whereEqualTo("section", sectionNumber).get()
            .addOnCompleteListener {result ->
                if (result.isSuccessful) {
                    for (document in result.result) {
                        val name = document.data["_name"].toString()
                        val price = document.data["price"].toString()
                        val section = document.data["section"].toString()

                        var ingredients = arrayOf(document.data["ingredients"].toString()
                            .replace("[", "")
                            .replace("]", "")).toString()

                        var commasCount = 0
                        for (letters in ingredients.indices) {

                            if (ingredients[letters].toString() == ",") {
                                commasCount++

                                if (commasCount == 4) {
                                    commasCount = 0
                                    ingredients = arrayOf(ingredients.replaceRange(letters, letters + 2, ", \\n ")).toString()
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        data.add(PizzaViewModel(name, price, section, arrayOf(ingredients)))
                        data.sortBy { it.name }
                        val adapter = PizzaCustomAdapter(data, baseContext)
                        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
                    }
                }
            }
```

Thanks in advance to everyone that will try to help me.

Comment: Currently your code is counting the commas, when it hits the fourth one it replaces all of the commas with a newline character (\n), you could achieve the desired result either by hard coding the index of the second comma (bad way cause the string may change and then it will not work), or by using .replaceRange or (probably the best way) by using regex to find the second comma and modify the string after getting it

Comment: Should it add the new line after every 4th (4th, 8th, 12th, etc) comma or just the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

couple of issues with your code:

- `replace` returns new string
- `var commasCount = 0` should be outside loop
- `commasCount` should be reset once reached 4

try this out:

```
var ingredients = "One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six"
var commasCount = 0
for (letters in ingredients.indices) {

    if (ingredients[letters].toString() == ",") {
        commasCount++

        if (commasCount == 4) {
            commasCount = 0
            ingredients = ingredients.replaceRange(letters, letters + 2, ", \n")
        }
    }
}
```

Output will be:

```
One, Two, Three, Four,
Five, Six, Two, Three
Four, Five, Six
```

UPDATE: convert it to array after adding new line

```
database.collection("Pizze").whereEqualTo("section", sectionNumber).get()
            .addOnCompleteListener {result ->
                if (result.isSuccessful) {
                    for (document in result.result) {
                        val name = document.data["_name"].toString()
                        val price = document.data["price"].toString()
                        val section = document.data["section"].toString()

                        var ingredients = document.data["ingredients"].toString()
                            .replace("[", "")
                            .replace("]", "")

                        var commasCount = 0
                        for (letters in ingredients.indices) {

                            if (ingredients[letters].toString() == ",") {
                                commasCount++

                                if (commasCount == 4) {
                                    commasCount = 0
                                    ingredients = ingredients.replaceRange(letters, letters + 2, ", \n")
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        data.add(PizzaViewModel(name, price, section, arrayOf(ingredients)))
                        data.sortBy { it.name }
                        val adapter = PizzaCustomAdapter(data, baseContext)
                        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Tried both ways, seems like I am missing something, I updated my question with the output in the app.

Comment: can you paste your whole code for above, how did you get value `[Ljava.lang.String@1c7172b`

Comment: Added all the database query, everything is a String except for the ingredients that are stored as an array but I need a single string

Comment: @Davide why are you converting it to array of
```

Comment: Because I need it to be an array to use it in a listview. It's declared as Array<String> in the ViewModel.

Comment: so it will be one string with newline but array form? if so, check updated answer in a sec

Comment: check the updated section with fix

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the answer, sorry for the 6 hours waiting

Answer (score 1):

You could do this

```
fun main() {
    val string = "One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine"
    val result = string.split(", ")
        .chunked(4)
        .joinToString(",\n") { it.joinToString(", ") }
    println(result)
}
```

Output:

```
One, Two, Three, Four,
Five, Six, Seven, Eight,
Nine
```

Comment: Nice approach, but there is the comma missing at the end of the first two lines. You could change `joinToString("\n")` to `joinToString(",\n")`, then there is the comma like in the expected output as stated in the question.

Comment: @KarstenGabriel you're right. I didn't properly look at the expected output. Though the code he tried made me think he didn't really want commas there. But I've made the change to my answer